# How to make multiple string queries on DJANGO 2.2

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to make a query to search my table peoples on field name all rows that contains some word in a `snames` var:

```
snames='john bush george robert'
```

I do it on SQL with bellow code:

```
SELECT * FROM names.peoples 
WHERE `name` LIKE'%john%bush%george%robert%';
```

and in django :

```
snames='john bush george robert'
p = peoples.objects.all().filter(name__icontains=snames)
```

Is it possible in a single query?

Comment: i advice to use [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) instead ->  `... WHERE (name) MATCH AGAINST('john bush ..' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add names in a list then with [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) you can `OR` filtering on `name` field's value:

```
sname = ['john', 'bush', 'george', 'robert']
condition = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(name__icontains=name) for name in sname])
p = Peoples.objects.filter(condition).distinct()
```

maybe condition line isn't clear for you so below is a sample output of condition:

```
Q(name__icontains='john') OR Q(name__icontains='bush') OR Q(name__icontains='george') OR Q(name__icontains='rober')
```

notice when you want query the model's name is capital.your using `poeples.objects.filter` in your code hope it is hypo , the correct is `Poeples.objects.filter`.